# Identity range issue in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

My application was working fine all these days. Recently when I try adding data, one of the table is throwing error

> The identity range managed by replication is full and must be updated
>   by a replication agent. The INSERT conflict occurred in database
>   'YourDatabase', table 'StillBillAccount', column 'ID'.
>   Sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange can be called to get a new identity
>   range.

I tried executing `Sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange` for a particular table, but without success.

Any solution please.

Thanks in advance,